# Removing time from a date-time field

Tags: ruby

In a field the date and time is set like "10/9/2014 7:43 PM".

I want to remove the time and need only the date so that I compare it with today's date. I.e., I want only `"10/9/2014"`.

Could anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: This isn't related to Watir at all, it's pure Ruby.

Comment: Where is this *field*? In a form? In a database? Just a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a string or a DateTime object?

If it's a DateTime object, just use `to_date` that will convert it to date:

```
 myDate.to_date
```

If it's a String, just `split` it and get the first part:

```
"10/9/2014 7:43 PM".split(' ').first
=> "10/9/2014"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

```
require 'date'
date = Date.parse  "10/9/2014 7:43 PM"
# => #<Date: 2014-09-10 ((2456911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.to_s # => "2014-09-10"
```

Another way using [`Date::strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime)

```
date = Date.strptime("10/9/2014 7:43 PM", "%d/%m/%Y %l:%M %p")
# => #<Date: 2014-09-10 ((2456911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.to_s # => "2014-09-10"
```

Comment: Using `strptime` is safer, since it's easy for `parse` to be confused by U.S. dates.

Comment: I agree 100%.. That's why I considered it to add. :-)

Comment: in that case, strptime is useless if you do parsing requiring a specific format then to_s -> much more effective to juste keep the string

Comment: `parse` has known problems when dealing with dates in `'%m/%d/%Y'` formats, which is common in the U.S., but not common elsewhere. `parse` assumes that '1/31/2014' is in '%d/%m/%Y' format and blows up: `require 'date';
Date.parse('1/30/2014') 
# ~> -:2:in 'parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)
# ~>  from -:2:in '<main>'`. To avoid that we use a known good pattern. Parsing then using `to_s` normalizes the output, or allows us to use `strftime` to specify a specific format.

Comment: @tomsoft Nothing is _useless_. I follow the standard approach. Why should I consider the _date_ as a _string_.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date:

```
d = DateTime.new(2014, 10, 9, 7, 43, 0)
d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") -> Gives "10/09/2014
```

or you can do `d.strftime("%D")`